# Docker apps inside iframes

Tags: docker, iframe, reverse-proxy

Say, I have a purely frontend platform that has specific GUI elements (header, sidebar..), but its content comes from different Dockerized apps. These apps reside inside iframes, generating some html on their own, but at the same time share header etc elements of the parent page.

Now, suppose platform is accessible at http://myplatform.com/, and Docker apps are reverse-proxied in the following maner:

http://myplatform.com/app1 --> goes to http://app1 (container with name app1)
http://myplatform.com/app2 --> goes to http://app2 and so on

This means, iframes will have src=http://myplatform.com/app1|app2|...

But if someone inputs http://myplatform.com/app1 manually in the address bar,
they will get raw Docker html content, without platform GUI elements.

**My question:**
is there a way to prevent this kind of behavior? Say, track if request was issued not from the platform, but manually/from another site. Or I am just fundamentally wrong with my approach? Please note, I am new to the world of Docker, reverse proxies and such.

Answer (score 0):

In dockerized app, verify that the request is from iframe and the location url is correct.
You can do this by adding this script to app, that is requested in iframe:

```
if (window.parent === window.top) {
    console.log('I am displayed from main window');
} else {
    console.log('I am displayed from iframe');
}
```